# DLib: what input arguments to be used in draw_rectangle()

Tags: c++, dlib

what are these input arguments used in `draw_rectangle` function in `Dlib`:

1. `image_type& img`
2. `const rectangle& rect`
3. `const pixel_type& val`
4. `unsigned int thickness`

can somebody please tell me what are these parameters and what value should i use to draw the overlays of found landmark on input image as to save it.

Comment: If there is no documentation explaining this, you should use a different library that has such a documentation.

Comment: @nvoigt I can not use different library, **Dlib** is the only one to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <
    typename image_type,
    typename pixel_type
    >
void draw_rectangle (
    image_type& img,
    const rectangle& rect,
    const pixel_type& val,
    unsigned int thickness = 1
);
/*!
    requires
        - image_type == an image object that implements the interface defined in
          dlib/image_processing/generic_image.h 
        - pixel_traits<pixel_type> is defined
    ensures
        - Draws the given rectangle onto the image img.  It does this by calling
          draw_line() four times to draw the four sides of the rectangle.  
        - The rectangle is drawn with the color given by val.
        - The drawn rectangle will have edges that are thickness pixels wide.
!*/
```

This is what their internet page says. It seems quite self-explanatory. You need an **image** to draw to, you need the **rectangle** you want to draw, the pixel_type denotes a **color** and the **thickness** is the thickness of the lines, that defaults to one pixel.

You can find more information about what an **image** is for this library [here](http://dlib.net/dlib/image_processing/generic_image.h.html) and you can read about the different **pixel_type**s right on their front page [here](http://dlib.net/imaging.html).

From your question I would say you may want to learn some more C++ first, especially templates, as this library makes heavy use of them. There are lots of functions and you cannot come here asking this question about every single one of them.

Comment: Hi I am using dlib in iOS for object detection, but it takes almost 30 secs to detect faces from image. Any workaround for this to increase performance.

Comment: @TheiCoder Hi, please ask a new question for this.